# SQLite transaction and RxJava

Tags: android-sqlite, rx-java, rx-android

There is how I save my data with RxJava:

```
override fun put(note: Note): Observable<Note> {
    validateNote(note)
    return Observable.just(note)
            .doOnNext { dbKeeper.startTransaction() }
            .doOnNext { storeHashtags(note) }
            .doOnNext { storeImages(note) }
            .flatMap { notesDataStore.put(notesMapper.transform(note)) }
            .map { notesMapper.transform(it) }
            .doOnNext { dbKeeper.setTransactionSuccessful() }
            .doOnUnsubscribe { dbKeeper.endTransaction() }
}
```

And then I use this method like this:

```
      notesManager.put(note)
            .switchMap { notesManager.getHashtags() }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {view.setHashtags(it) }
```

And `doOnUnsubscribe` never called as `getHashtags()` trying to SELECT from db that locked by `startTransaction()`. Deadlock, heh.
Okay. Let's replace `doOnUnsubscribe(...)` with `doOnTerminate(...)`.

```
override fun put(note: Note): Observable<Note> {
    validateNote(note)
    return Observable.just(note)
            .doOnNext { dbKeeper.startTransaction() }
            .doOnNext { storeHashtags(note) }
            .doOnNext { storeImages(note) }
            .map { notesMapper.transform(note) }
            .flatMap { notesDataStore.put(it) }
            .map { notesMapper.transform(it) }
            .doOnNext { dbKeeper.setTransactionSuccessful() }
            .doOnTerminate { dbKeeper.endTransaction() }
}
```

But now transaction won't close if `Observable` will be interrupted by `subscriber.unsubscribe()`.

What can you recommend to solve my situation?

Additional information:
I use one writableDb instance to write/read data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this isn't a good fit for Rx; My recommendation would be to do the transaction using the usual try-finally (pardon the Java):

```
Observable<Note> put(Note note) {
   return just(note)
        .doOnNext(n -> {
            validateNote(n);
            dbKeeper.startTransaction();
            try {
              storeHashtags(n);
              storeImages(n);
              notesDataStore.put(notesMapper.transform(n));
              dbKeeper.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } finally {
              dbKeeper.endTransaction();
            }
         });
}
```

Edit: Maybe this is more useful:

```
fun <T> withTransaction(sourceObservable: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    val latch = AtomicInteger(1)
    val maybeEndTransaction = Action0 {
        if (latch.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
            endTransaction()
        }
    }
    return Observable.empty<T>()
            .doOnCompleted { startTransaction() }
            .mergeWith(sourceObservable)
            .doOnNext { setTransactionSuccessful() }
            .doOnTerminate(maybeEndTransaction)
            .doOnUnsubscribe(maybeEndTransaction)
}
```

Use it like this:

```
override fun put(note: Note): Observable<Note> {
  return Observable.just(note)
        .doOnNext { validateNote(note) }
        .doOnNext { storeHashtags(note) }
        .doOnNext { storeImages(note) }
        .flatMap { notesDataStore.put(notesMapper.transform(note)) }
        .map { notesMapper.transform(it) }
        .compose { withTransaction }
}
```

It will ensure that the transaction ends exactly once; just be careful that you don't switch threads within your original observable chain (unless your transaction amanger can handle that, or you modified your schedulers to associate new threads with existing transactions).

Comment: Yeah, I already understood that Rx is not suitable for this case. But it's too late to change project's architecture. Thanks for your solution. Maybe I will use `BlockingObservable` for `notesDataStore.put()` and similar methods.

Comment: Looks interesting, I will try it. Thanks!